# how to join two tables from different databases?

Tags: php, mysql

Database 1 : sandbox

table 1    : coordinates

```
+----------------------------------------+
|coord_id | section_name | station_number|
+----------------------------------------+
|   1     |    A         |  A7           |
|   2     |    B         |  B20          |
|   3     |    C         |  C3           |
|   4     |    D         |  D14          |
|   5     |    E         |  E9           |
+----------------------------------------+
```

database 2 : phone

table 2    : workstations

I only have READ privilege

```
+----------------------------+
|   ID  |       ws    |  pod |
+----------------------------+
|    1  |  COMP123  |  A07   |
|  2    |  COMP345  |  B20   |
|  3    |  COMP567  |  C03   |
|  4    |  COMP891  |  D14   |
|  5    |  COMP444  |  E09   |
+----------------------------+
```

**PROBLEM:**

I only have READ privilege on that second table of that database.

I want to join both tables so I can display the "ws" field on screen for my PHP script.
My "station_number" field values are written differently from the "pod" field 
(they have a zero in front of the letter if it is a single digit after the letter) does it make a difference?

I've seen examples online on how to join but for some reason I can't get it to work.

Do I need to create an extra field on my main Table to store the field values from "ws" or what? I'm a bit confused.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply add the database name before the table name you want to join, that's it. `... LEFT JOIN db2.table1 ON db1.table1.column1 = db2.table1.column1 ... `

Comment: What is the relation between the two?

Comment: Yes. It makes a difference.

Comment: @KouberSaparev station_number and pod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it makes a difference if there's a 0 in one and not in the other. You'll have to modify the value of one or the other. Something like `SUBSTR(station_number, 0, 1) + LPAD(SUBSTR(station_number, 2), 2, '0')`.

And to join the tables from different databases, you just have to put the database name in front of the table name. Probably something like `sandbox.coordinates`.

So your query might look something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sandbox.coordinates c
    INNER JOIN phone.workstations w
        ON (SUBSTR(c.station_number, 0, 1) + LPAD(SUBSTR(c.station_number, 2), 2, '0')) = w.pod
```

---

If you can update one of your tables to make the columns match, then your query is as simple as:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sandbox.coordinates c
    INNER JOIN phone.workstations w
        ON c.station_number = w.pod
```

Comment: I see, so I'll update my table to include the zero. thanks

Comment: wouldn't it be SELECT ws, pod FROM ... if I want to display the **ws** field with their matching station_number? thanks

Comment: Yes, it is better to specify the actual columns you want instead of just using `SELECT *`. If those are the columns you want, then you would use `SELECT w.ws, w.pod FROM ...`. Is the purpose of the JOIN to only select rows that have a corresponding entry in the `coordinates` table? If so, then that's perfectly fine, but I ask because if not, you aren't selecting any rows from that table or doing any further filtering in it (aside from making sure it exists).

Comment: nicely explain, thank you your help it helped me understand and is working as I wanted! :D